# Printable Vue Full Calendar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, printing, fullcalendar

We're porting over our old Full Calendar (FC) implementation to vue and was trying to restore the printable functionality that we utilized. But upon inspecting the FC Node modules I didn't see any CSS related to printing.

After several Google searches that yielded no results, I began to get a little nervous at the thought of having to code it out myself.

Is there a piece that I'm missing here? perhaps a separate node module that I missed in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#main)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upgrade guide at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3 says

> No need to use a separate  tag for a print-only stylesheet. It will be automatically included within the normal core/main.css, by use of media queries

So based on that in v4 you should be able to print correctly by default without including any extra files.